# Angularjs - Spring MVC : make server push data to client without being asked for it

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

On a HTML view I have a label that displays the number of fruit boxes that are sold by a company.

I want this number to be updated without calling a Spring MVC resource.
I mean each time a sale is achieved (done on server side), I would like Spring MVC to push data to Angularjs in order to update the number of fruit boxes without having to refresh the view.

In a normal behaviour, Angularjs make a call to Spring and receive a result. Here I want Angularjs to received a result without making the call.

I hope my question is clear... (not sure though)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure websockets for tomcat.
[Tomcat 8 websocket](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html)

Your angular app will then be able to receive events sent from the server using `$rootScope.on` events

EDIT:

The actual link is this [configure websockets in spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html).
and you have a detailed tutorial on the [spring.io page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: Why Tomcat? And how can you actually send and receive data?

Comment: You didn't mention a server so with spring I assumed tomcat. What do you use server side?